# Given f[1] ... f[k], k = 1, 2, 3... how do one find the general function f[n]?

Tags: recursion, code-request

If I have that

```
f[1] = 2 a b;
f[2] = 2 a b (1 + 6 a);
f[3] = 2 a b (1 + 9 a + 12 a^2);
f[4] = 2 a b (1 + 21 a + 72 a^2 + 60 a^3);
f[5] = 2 a b (1 + 45 a + 300 a^2 + 600 a^3 + 360 a^4);
f[6] = 2 a b (1 + 93 a + 1080 a^2 + 3900 a^3 + 5400 a^4 + 2520 a^5);
f[7] = 2 a b (1 + 189 a + 3612 a^2 + 21000 a^3 + 50400 a^4 + 52920 a^5 + 20160 a^6);
```

etc, how can I find a rule for $f(n)$ ?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with _Mathematica_?

Comment: I hope that mathematica can solve this problem, but I don't know how.

Comment: `FindGeneratingFunction` and `FindSequenceFunction` do this, but they probably won't work for such a general symbolic sequence.

Comment: can you add f(5) and f(6) also if possible?

Comment: f(5)=2ab(1+45a+300a^2+600a^3+360a^4), f(6)=2ab(1+93a+1080a^2+3900a^3+5400a^4+2520a^5)

Comment: Thank you  Szabolcs.  I tried FindGeneratingFunction and FindSequenceFunction on the expression in the brackets but it doesn't work. May rule doesn't exist :(

Comment: Can you give some idea as to where these formulas are coming from?  Perhaps the origin will help illuminate the pattern of the sequence.  I doubt *Mathematica* can divine the pattern without additional input.

Comment: `InterpolatingPolynomial[{2a b,2a b(1+6a),2a b(1+9a+12a^2),2a b(1+21a+72a^2+60a^3),2a  b(1+45a+300a^2+600a^3+360a^4),2a b(1+93a+1080a^2+3900a^3+5400a^4+2520a^5)},x]//Simplify`

Comment: Damn! I love how powerful MMA is. +1.

Comment: Thank you. InterpolatingPolynomial works only for n=1,...6. But obtained rule doesn't work when I put n=7,8... , i.e do not get the appropriate formula by using the obtained polynomial for n=7,8... I can't explain the nature of the formulas. It is to complicated. I am not sure that rule exists. I only assume that there is a rule, because I need rule.

Comment: I replaced the LaTeX with *Mathematica* code; please confirm that I entered it correctly.

Comment: @Maya If you have the polynomial for `n=7`, `n=8` please include them.

Comment: f(7)=2ab(1+189a+3612a^2+21000a^3+50400a^4+52920a^5+20160a^6)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following answer is based on the assumption that you made a mistake in your opening post and that the term `f[2] = 2 a b (1 + 6 a)` is actually supposed to be `f[2] = 2 a b (1 + 3 a)`, i.e. with a 3 replacing the 6.

---

Let's first concentrate on the coefficients. Later we can easily construct the polynomials from them. The following image illustrates the pattern behind the coefficients:

[image: series]

To describe this pattern, let $(k,n)$ denote the $k^\mathrm{th}$ coefficient in the $n^\mathrm{th}$ row. Each row starts with a one, i.e. $(1,n)=1$ for all $n$. The last coefficient is always equal to the last of the previous row  multiplied by $n+1$. Thus $(n,n)=(n-1,n-1)\cdot(n+1)$ for all $n\neq1$. The ones in between are constructed by

$$(k,n)=k\cdot(k,n-1)+(k+1)\cdot(k-1,n-1).$$

I used `Fold` to implement this sequence. You can see that I used the above rules for the `First` and `Last` elements of each iteration. The ones in between are computed in the `Table`.

```
coefficients[n_Integer] :=
 Fold[Join[
    {First@#1},
    Table[k #1[[k]] + (k + 1) #1[[k - 1]], {k, 2, #2}],
    {(#2 + 2) Last@#1}] &,
  {1},
  Range[n - 1]]
```

And indeed this creates the same coefficients as in your opening post (again with the 6 replaced by 3).

```
Grid[coefficients /@ Range@7]
(*
1                       
1   3                   
1   9   12              
1   21  72  60          
1   45  300 600 360     
1   93  1080    3900    5400    2520    
1   189 3612    21000   50400   52920   20160 *)
```

Now, the polynomials can be created with `FromDigits`:

```
f[n_Integer] :=
 2 a b Expand@FromDigits[Reverse@coefficients@n, a]
```

Finally, test with some `n`:

```
f[11]
(*
2 a (1 + 3069 a + 342012 a^2 + 8745000 a^3 + 88822800 a^4 + 
   452307240 a^5 + 1289977920 a^6 + 2155507200 a^7 + 2095632000 a^8 + 
   1097712000 a^9 + 239500800 a^10) b *)
```

---

For those inclined to terse coding the `coefficients` function could be written as:

```
g[1] := {1}

g[n_] := g[n - 1] /. {x__} :> ({0, x} (# + 1) + {x, 0} # & @ Range[n])
```

Test:

```
g[7]
```

> ```
> {1, 189, 3612, 21000, 50400, 52920, 20160}
> ```

Comment: Nice catch! :) +1

Comment: And nice work finding and illustrating a pattern. +1!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for the edit! I knew someone would come up with a more concise way to code it. I'm not surprised it's you! `:)`

Comment: You're welcome. :D

Comment: @einbandi Wow, wow, wow. You are a genius :) I am impressed. Thank You very much. Yes, it was mistake, 6 should be replaced with 3. I apologize for the confusion. Thanks again :)

Comment: I also like to thank to @Mr.Wizard . Thank You :)

Comment: @einbandi  I am new here and I forgot the points :) +15

Comment: @Maya I think you intended to Accept this answer but somehow you did not.  See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) for a full explanation of the system.  By the way you're welcome for my small part in this.

Comment: @einbandi,BTW,what software do you use to achieve the picture?

Comment: @ShutaoTang I quickly scrambled it together in inkscape, but with some effort it could be done more beautifully in LaTeX.

Comment: @einbandi,Thanks a lot!:-)

Answer (score 3):

Using the insight from **einbandi** just another way to produce pattern:

```
fun[u_] := Module[{lg},
  lg = Length[u];
  PadLeft[u Range[3, lg + 2], lg + 1] + PadRight[u Range[lg], lg + 1]]

pol[v_] := (a^Range[0, Length@v - 1]).v
```

Nesting:

```
grd = Grid[
  Transpose[{TraditionalForm[f[#]] & /@ Range[1, 7], 
    HoldForm[2 a b  #] & /@ (pol /@ NestList[fun, {1}, 6])}], 
  Alignment -> Left, Frame -> {{True, True}, None}, 
  Background -> {None, {{LightBlue, White}}}]
```

[image]